# Umbraco Backoffice Login stop working suddenly

Tags: umbraco

I am using UmbracoCMS 7.6.2 in one of my site.

Today when I tried to login in Umbraco backoffice using mysite/umbraco, will my working credential, it shows me error:

> Login failed for user admin

As, login for 'Admin' was working fine till today and suddenly stops working.

I checked the console of the browser and getting following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request) umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/PostLogin

[image]

I check the log files and getting following error:

> Umbraco.Core.Security.BackOfficeSignInManager - Event Id: 0, state:
>   Login attempt failed for username admin from IP address, the user is
>   locked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it finally working.

I've change the useLegacyEncoding="false" to true and it starts working normally.

Comment: That's really weird, i changed false to true then true to false and now it works....

Comment: What worked for me is setting the useLegacyEncoding="true" on the usersMembershipProvider, not on the umbracoMembershipProvider section

Answer (score 6):

You probably tried to login with the wrong password too many times and umbraco locked you out.

To fix this go to the database, open `umbracoUser` table and update `userNoConsole` to 0 for your username.

Comment: I've checked my database, credential is correct. also the field for userNoConsole is false

Comment: yes. I cleared cookie. tried in multiple browsers, incognito mode and recycle iis application pool of godaddy

Comment: open umbracoUser table and update userNoConsole to 0 for your username.

It Works :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Umbraco version 7.7.4 assembly: 1.0.6505.22489. I have tried different ways to solve the problem.

I got a solution when I synchronized my local database with my online database.

The problem was on the table umbracoServer and umbracoUser. I only updated those, and my backoffice started working again.