# Unable to log in Umbraco on local server

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have taken a fresh clone of my site running in Umbraco cloud and I am trying to run it but keep being redirected to login page where despite correct credentials i get invalid user error and an error in console as well. I am using version 7.13.2. I have tried clearing cache, restarting environment, checking the Db for user and also checked the user lockout value but nothing seems to work
[Umbraco Backoffice error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pig82.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow! Could you edit your question to include the messages that appear in your console? This may help others going through the same issue to find your question. It may also attract an answer more quickly!

Comment: It appears your question is very similar to the linked one. Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45409216/umbraco-backoffice-login-stop-working-suddenly resolves your issue, otherwise there are other related questions in the sidebar. If none of them answers your question, please [edit] your question to provide additional details like logs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL on the screenshot, you need to run an upgrade.

(localhost:4670/umbraco/**AuthorizeUpgrade**)

For this you need to log in with an administrator user that has privilege to do that.

If you have just restored the database and your Umbraco code version is the same as on the other machine, then you could also check the **web.config** file.

There is a key called `"Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus"`. At start Umbraco checks if the version number is matching the one in the database. After running the upgrade Umbraco updates that key too.

In your case it should look like:

```
<add key="Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus" value="7.13.2" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Crick3t but i am trying to log in with the admin user to authorize but it is still giving the same errors as shown in attached screenshot